# Powershell Get-TransportRule read full data of a transport rule property

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

```
Get-TransportRule "Gmail Block" | Select-Object "ExceptIfFrom" | Format-List
```

returns the results

```
ExceptIfFrom : {terer.nolt@gmail.com, calendar-notification@google.com, brianqfaanur@gmail.com, cced1rley657@gmail.com...}
```

How would I request the entire list?

Comment: Add `-ExpandProperty` to your select.  `Get-TransportRule "Gmail Block" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "ExceptIfFrom"`

Comment: You don't see the entire list because of `$formatenumerationlimit` automatic variable is set to `4` by default. This governs how many items in a property's value collection are visible before being truncated in the console display. Set `$formatenumerationlimit = -1` and then run this command.

Answer (score 1):

Update `$formatenumerationlimit` to a value equal to or larger than your collection size:

```
# -1 is unlimited
$formatenumerationlimit = -1
```

---

When an object's property value is a collection and you are using a view that displays the property/value pair, `$formatenumerationlimit` automatic variable determines how many items in the collection are visible before being truncated. The default value is `4`.

You can easily replicate this situation with a simple object:

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{property = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
$obj
```

**Output:**

```
property
--------
{1, 2, 3, 4...}
```

Now update `$formatenumerationlimit`

```
$formatenumerationlimit = 9
$obj
$formatenumerationlimit = -1
$obj
```

**Output:**

```
property
--------
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

property
--------
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

---

Alternatively, retrieving only the property's value will likely display all list items and is not impacted by `$formatenumerationlimit`.

```
$obj.property
$obj | Select-Object -ExpandProperty property
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```